# Ubuntu 22.04, Wayland will not indicate keyboard language input switch when using Alt+Shift

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-layout, wayland

When I switch keyboard layouts in Ubuntu 22.04 via Alt+Shift, the indicator on the top menu does not change. This only happens on Wayland, on X it works fine. I think I saw a bug report somewhere, but I still can not find a fix. Does anybody know of ways to get the indicator working? It's very annoying as I'm never sure which language I'm on when unlocking the screen and have to enter the password multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my problem and solution:

I used `gnome-tweaks` to configure Alt+Shift to switch between layouts. Apparently, this does not work well with keyboard indicator. What needs to happen is I should use `gsettings` to configure such switch [as described here](https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2021/11/14/use-alt-shift-for-keyboard-layout-switching-in-gnome-40/).

After turning the setting off in `gnome-tweaks` I ran following, and now indicator is in sync with current layout:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Shift>Alt_L']"
```

Answer (score 2):

Settings in `GNOME` are stored in two different components:

- GSettings (API for application settings)
- dconf database (key-based db; back end for GSettings)

If some settings do not work correctly for a reason, you can interact with dconf db directly, most of the times it will work then.

---

As mentioned by [@galets](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/14554/galets), you can run the following command from the **command line**

```bash
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Shift>Alt_L']"
```

And if you prefer a **GUI** application, you can try out `dconf-editor`. Simply install it with `sudo apt install dconf-editor`

From there navigate to your setting `org > gnome > desktop > wm > keybindings > switch-input-source` or search for `switch-input-source` in the search bar.

---

Hope that helped you further :)